# Enable option to change new tab page in browser

Tags: firefox

I have the latest version of Mozilla Firefox. I want to change the new tab page to google.com. I found a solution that I must go to **about:config** and find  `browser.newtab.url` and then change its value.

But when I go to **about:config**, `browser.newtab.url` doesn't exist anymore.

Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

`browser.newtab.url` was removed in Firefox 41, because of its potential for abuse. (see [#1118285](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1118285))

There is an [addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/new-tab-override/) which you can use instead.